# Always assign the same bluetooth dongle the same linux identifier hci0

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-os

we have a Raspberry Pi that is always listening for Bluetooth devices and if some conditions for the peripheral apply, it opens a Bluetooth connection to write some data to the peripheral.
For performance optimizations, there is one Bluetooth Dongle only for listening and another one that does the connections/writing. In our scripts, we hardwired hci0 to be the listening device and hci1 to connect.

Now we have the problem, that if somebody unplugs the dongle during runtime and plugs it back in, the device will receive the name hci2. This of course breaks our scripts.

So, my question is: Can I configure my Raspberry Pi OS to always assign the same name to the dongle? I would imagine, as they are using the MAC of the Dongle as an identifier, this should be possible.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hardcode `hci0` and `hci1` in your code, I would look up the value for the mac address.

I'll assume you are using the D-Bus API and so could use `GetManagedObjects`.

For example:

```py
import pydbus


bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
mngr = bus.get('org.bluez', '/')


def get_hci(address):
    mngd_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()
    for path in mngd_objs:
        device_info = mngd_objs[path].get('org.bluez.Adapter1', {}).get('Address', 'none')
        if device_info  == address: 
            return path

print(get_hci('B8:27:EB:22:33:44'))
# /org/bluez/hci0
```

Comment: Thanks ukBaz. As we are deploying the code to many of these machines, we shouldn't mix the code with hard-wiring the MAC address. I could imagine a solution where the code is invoked with environment vars, that contain the MACs. But still, is there no solution that just uses Linux tools?